# What is correct API endpoint?

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing API endpoints like that but there is a fuzzy thing in here.
These endpoints are working on CompanyKeyword table that has CompanyId and KeywordId. So this table is related to the Company and the Keyword table.

I will get all company keywords and specific company keyword with below endpoints, respectively.

When I looked at [REST API: Design Guidelines](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/rest-api-how-to-bce359ad7362) on internet. Guideline says

> If a relationship can only exist within another resource, use then
>   according to it.

This is guiding me to below endpoints:

```
[HttpGet("api/company/{companyId}/keyword/{keywordId}")]
[HttpGet("api/company/{companyId}/keyword")]
```

But I am not using companyId and keywordId in my backend code. I just need companyKeywordId.

Because of that I am using endpoint like below.

```
(1)
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
{
   // Some Code
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
   // Some Code
}
```

When I looked at the internet, if companyId and keywordId are being used in the code than they are being requested from endpoint. If they aren't necessary then they aren't being requested from api endpoint.

```
(2)
[HttpGet("api/company/{companyId}/keyword")]
[HttpGet("api/company/{companyId}/keyword/{keywordId}")]
```

I am confused. Which one is correct, 1 or 2?

Could you help me about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of consistency and clarity. By looking at the requests:

```
api/company/{companyId}/keyword
api/company/{companyId}/keyword/{keywordId}
```

I know i am getting a list of keywords for `companyId`or a specific keyword `keywordId` for `companyId`. This is a clear api request because i can determine the result i'm getting by looking at the url.

Now if the url would change, because i dont really need the `companyId` on the backend

```
api/keyword/{keywordId}
```

Then from the URL i can no longer determine where this keyword belongs to. In fact, its not even clear that you actually need it to belong to a company.

If the resource falls under a different resource, then write it in the url for clarity, even if you dont actually need the associated id.

**Having said that**; why wouldn't you use the `companyId`, even if you dont need it? As a user of your API i might think that keyword 342 belongs to company 589, but what if it doesnt? The url `api/keyword/342` would still return it because you are not including the company id in the select statement. So use any identifier in your url to make your call, even if it doesnt ***seem*** to make sense.

```
select * from keywords where companyId = 589 and keywordId = 342;
```